# Why does the for loop behave like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

When I run the program, the for loop does not delete all the list items, but only certain ones. Why?
Here is the code:

```
def res(array):
   for i in range(len(array)):
      print(array[i])
      del array[i]
      print(array)

arr = [10, 5, 40, 30, 20, 50]
res(arr)
```

Comment: The first time through the loop you delete `array[0]`, and all of the other items shift down one position.  Then the next time through the loop you delete `array[1]`, and the new `array[0]` remains untouched.

Comment: Because if you delete the item, then the remaining items shift one to the right, but still you increment `i`, so you move two items forward so to speak. It will normally also raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: Do not delete any element while iterating. Will create issues similar to what you are facing.

Comment: use while loop `while arr:
    print(arr.pop(0))`

Comment: But the general advise is: *never* modify a collection while iterating over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're modifying the list while you're deleting items in it.
First you delete the first item, 10.
Everything shifts, 5 is now the first item.
Then you delete the second item, which is now 40, etc.

Not sure what you want to accomplish, but going through the list in reverse 
for i in range(len(list)-1,-1,-1) 
might do it for you.

Comment: How iterating in reverse will solve the issue?

Comment: Because this will delete the last item, which will not change the index of any of the other items

Comment: Why? If I want to delete the elements at first index and middle index then? A general piece of advice does not change the list while iterating over it.

Comment: That is for sure true, that is a different "use case", if you like. And I would also agree with you to not delete while iterating.